# Handling <br> tag in xpath through cucumber

Tags: xpath, cucumber, selenide

I'm using cucumber with Selenide frameworks, I have the following step in cucumber's regression.feature file:

```
Then Check if has a section labelled "Foo bar foo bar"
```

In Steps.java file I have:

```
@Then("^Check if has a section labelled \"([^\"]*)\"$")
public void checkThatHomePageHassectionLabelled(String arg0) throws Throwable {
    servicesSectionCheck(arg0);
}
```

And I would like to check if:

```
public static void servicesSectionCheck(String name) {
    $(byXpath("//h1[(text()='" + name + "')]")).shouldBe(visible);
}
```

The problem is sometimes when the browser is smaller (RWD issue), the HTML is looking like

```
<div id="services" class="page_section row">
<input type="hidden" id="Count1" value="4">
<input type="hidden" id="Count2" value="2">
<input type="hidden" id="Count3" value="10">
<input type="hidden" id="loadMoreServicesURL" value="anURLhere">
<input type="hidden" id="portletNamespace" value="_serviceslist_INSTANCE_t8TJHYdgnwCu_"> 
<div class="col-12 desktop-padding"> 
    <div class="d-none d-sm-block margin-top-50"></div> 
    <h1 class="text-center d-none d-sm-block">Foo bar <br> foo bar</h1> 
<div class="d-none d-sm-block margin-bottom-40"></div>(...)
```

And sometimes

```
<h1 class="text-center d-none d-sm-block">Foo bar foo bar</h1>
```

How can I set an Xpath in `servicesSectionCheck` function to pass despite if `<br>` tag is presented or not?

Comment: `"//h1/(text()='" + name + "')]"` doesn't seem to be valid XPath... Did you mean `"//h1[(text()='" + name + "')]"`?

Comment: Yes, wrong copied, sorry :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of evaluating child text node (`text()`) you can evaluate string representation of header:

```
//h1[normalize-space()='" + name + "']
```

Comment: Following xpath doesn't work, but I'm looking in this way, thanks :)

Comment: @Michal It should work with the provided HTML sample... Can you update your HTML sample if your simplified code source doesn't look like the real one? Also check whether your `name` variable is actually `"Foo bar foo bar"`, but not `"Foo barfoo bar"` or something else

Comment: Added. I spotted that this is `Foo bar foo bar`, but in HTML there's `Foo bar <br> foo bar`, but adding an additional space in the "Then" line changed nothing

Comment: And btw, the first option (as described in my question) is 99% times - I think about focusing overcoming this `<br>` tag first, then think about the second issue, if needed

Comment: @Michal this looks more complicated , but shuold cover all 3 cases (including the one before question was modified): `//h1[starts-with(., "Foo bar") and normalize-space(substring-after(., "Foo bar"))="foo bar"]`. With this XPath we can ignore `<br>` as well as spaces between 1st and 2nd text

Comment: Oh... We should use the `name` as single string, right?(( then this is just a workaround...

Comment: It'd be nice for evolution, if a similar case will be in the future it'd be good to have a function covering it already, but now I think this workaround will be enough :) thanks!